# How can I get the card layout of an jInternalPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cardlayout, jinternalframe

I have a `jInternalPane` within a `jDesktopPane`. The `jDesktopPane` is within a `jPanel` that has the `BorderLayout` layout.

In my internal pane, I am trying to programatically switch cards. I have the following, relevant piece of code that breaks:

```
public void switchCards() {
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(internalFrame1.getLayout());
    cl.show(internalFrame1, "card1"); //Where card1 is a jPanel
}
```

However, in the error trace, I can see the following:

`javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI$Handler cannot be cast to java.awt.CardLayout`.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to properly handle this error? I would love to learn how to do it!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: put JPanel to JInternalFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a CardLayout on the content pane of the JInternalFrame, not the internal frame itself.

You can just set the layout of the content pane:

```
Container contentPane = internalFrame.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout( new CardLayout() );

contentPane.add(panel1, "Card1");
contentPane.add(panel2, "Card2");
```

Then your switchCards() method would be:

```
Container contentPane = internalFrame.getContentPane();
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(contentPane.getLayout());
cl.show(contentPane, "card1"); //Where card1 is a jPanel
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I was off on a trip. Thank you for clearing up any confusion I had. Your code fully explained what I was missing, and I understand now.

Thank you for your time!